# CFT In Embedding Space

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, field-theory, group-theory, conformal-field-theory

I am trying to figure out how a translation or a conformal transformation explicitly look like in embedded space.
Given a CFT in Euclidian (or Minkowski) coordinates $x^\mu$ we can embedded them in $d+2$ dimensional space $$X^{M}=\left(X^{+},X^{-},X^{\mu}\right)=\left(1,x^{2},x^{\mu}\right)$$ or $$X^{M}=\left(X^{-1},X^{0},X^{\mu}\right)=\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{2},\frac{1+x^{2}}{2},x^{\mu}\right)$$
My question is, I'm trying to figure out how the transformation looks like on the embedded space.
For translation $\left(1,x^{2},x^{\mu}\right)\rightarrow\left(1,x^{2}-2ax+a^{2},x^{\mu}-a^{\mu}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{2},\frac{1+x^{2}}{2},x^{\mu}\right)\rightarrow\left(\frac{1-x^{2}+2ax-a^{2}}{2},\frac{1+x^{2}-2ax+a^{2}}{2},x^{\mu}-a^{\mu}\right)$ and for SCT $\left(1,x^{2},x^{\mu}\right)\rightarrow\left(1,\frac{x^{2}}{1-2ax+a^{2}x^{2}},\frac{x^{\mu}-a^{\mu}x^{2}}{1-2ax+a^{2}x^{2}}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{2},\frac{1+x^{2}}{2},x^{\mu}\right)\rightarrow\left(\frac{1-x^{2}-2ax+a^{2}x^{2}}{2},\frac{1+x^{2}-2ax+a^{2}x^{2}}{2},\frac{x^{\mu}-a^{\mu}x^{2}}{1-2ax+a^{2}x^{2}}\right)$.
I want to know what the rotation matrix in the embedded space looks like to get the correct scaling factor (none for translation and $1-2ax+a^{2}x^{2}$ for SCT).
For example for Dilatation the matrix for the coordinates $\left(X^{-1},X^{0},X^{\mu}\right)=\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{2},\frac{1+x^{2}}{2},x^{\mu}\right)$ would look as
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{I} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{\lambda+\lambda^{-1}}{2} & \frac{\lambda-\lambda^{-1}}{2}\\
0 & \frac{\lambda-\lambda^{-1}}{2} & \frac{\lambda+\lambda^{-1}}{2}
\end{array}\right)$$
And for $\left(X^{+},X^{-},X^{\mu}\right)=\left(1,x^{2},x^{\mu}\right)$ it would look like
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{I} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \lambda & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda^{-1}
\end{array}\right)$$
How it would look like for translations and SCT? (In either basis, I can just rotate between them)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in David Simmons-Duffin's ph229 lecture notes
https://github.com/davidsd/ph229/blob/master/ph229-notes.pdf